# birthday problem near misses

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, computability

I am working with a case of the Birthday problem with near misses.  (i.e. The probability that there are 2 or more collisions after selecting $n$ elements uniformly from a set of $m$ total elements where a collision is defined as falling within $k$ elements of any previously selected element)

I have the eq. from Wikipedia for the near miss formulation:

$$
p(n,k,m) = 1 - \frac{(m-nk-1)!}{m^{n-1}(m-n(k+1))!}
$$

My problem lies in computing the factorials.  I am working with numbers on the order of:

$$
m = 1000 * (2^{32}-1), n = 1000, k = 10000
$$

Even Wolfram Alpha gives up with those values.  Are there any formulations for this problem that don't involve the factorial or any approximation methods that could make this a reasonably commutable problem?  As an extension, is it then also possible to compute/approximate the expected number of collisions after selecting $n$ elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $ \frac{(m-nk-1)!}{(m-n(k+1))!}=\frac{(m-nk-1)!}{(m-nk-n)!}$ and note that there are $n-1$ terms that do not cancel out.  As $n \ll m$ they are all about the same size.  They average $m-nk-\frac n2$, so the fraction is about $(m-nk-\frac n2)^{n+1}$

A better approximation is [Stirling's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), $m! \approx (\frac me)^m \sqrt {2 \pi m}$ but the $m^m$ part of it may kill you.  You can take the log and evaluate the log of your expression.

Comment: I think you may have a typo in your second eq. in the denominator.  I believe it should be $m-nk-n$ instead of $m-nk+n$ along with an extra ')'.

Comment: @majorpain1588:  You are right.  The minus sign carries on downward to the end of the paragraph.  All the terms also are now in the numerator.  I have fixed it.