# Expected number of pairs with Hamming distance $d$ for a sample of $k$ random bit strings of length $n$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, binomial-coefficients, information-theory

Say we were to uniformly sample $k$ times from a bit string with length $n$. What is the expected number of pairs with a Hamming distance $d$? In the limit of Hamming distance 0, I realize this becomes a birthday collision problem, but I am interested in the general case.

For example, say we generate 1000 random 10-bit strings, what is the expected number of strings with a Hamming distance of 3?

I found several related posts: [Probability that a set of 'N' random binary strings are all at least a certain Hamming distance 'k' apart](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164737/probability-that-a-set-of-n-random-binary-strings-are-all-at-least-a-certain-h) , [birthday problem near misses](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2142484/birthday-problem-near-misses) , and [Average number of strings with edit distance exactly 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3488881/average-number-of-strings-with-edit-distance-exactly-2)
but I could not quite make the additional leap to answer my similar but not exactly the same question.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The question, as you have it worded right now, does not make sense to me. Maybe you meant to ask, "What is the expected number of **pairs of sampled strings** whose distance is $d$?". Is that a fair interpretation?

Comment: Hi, yes that is what I mean. Thanks for clarifying it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this seems quite easy

Let $A^d_{i,j}$ be the event that two strings $s_i$ $s_j$
have distance $d$. Then, if both $s_i,s_j$ are random, we have $$P(A^d_{i,j})= \binom{n}{d} 2^{-n}$$

Then, if we sample $k$ random strings, the expected number of pairs with such distance is

$$ \frac{k(k-1)}{2} \binom{n}{d} 2^{-n}$$

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. That makes total sense!

Answer (score 0):

Just adding extra clarity for myself here based on leonbloy's answer:

The probability that a pair of strings has Hamming distance $d$ follows a binomial distribution:
$$
P(X=d)=\binom{n}{d}(1/2)^d (1/2)^{n-d} = \frac{1}{2^n}\binom{n}{d} 
$$

as explained by [Probability that hamming distance is d.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527179/probability-that-hamming-distance-is-d)

Then, this probability is multiplied by the total number of pairings that can be made in a set of $k$ items. This can be found from the series:
$(k-1) + (k-2) + ... (k-(k-1))$ which reduces to $\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$